# Moving average for months over years

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am new to pandas and would appreciate guidance with the following problem. I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
In [88]: df.head()
Out[88]: 
       Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  ...    Dec
Year                               ...     
1758    13   15   14    5    5    5  ...     12
1759    11   10    7    4    3    6  ...     11
1760    19   15   18    5   13    6  ...     11
1761    14   16   14    9    9   11  ...     10
1762    13   12   12    8    5    3  ...     11
```

I need to compute moving average per month in the following way:

Moving_average of Mar_1761 = (value_of_Mar_1761)/(sum of values from Sep_1760 to Aug_1761)

If I am using the rolling average function of pandas, how do I code the logic to inspect predecessor or successor row for a particular point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is to reshape to data to a long format using [`.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking), which can be be passed straight into rolling mean.

```
In [34]: pd.rolling_mean(df.stack(), window=12)
Out[34]: 
Year     
1758  Jan         NaN
      Feb         NaN
      Mar         NaN
      Apr         NaN
      May         NaN
      Jun         NaN
      Jul         NaN
      Aug         NaN
      Sep         NaN
      Oct         NaN
      Nov         NaN
      Dec    0.035038
1759  Jan   -0.076660
      Feb   -0.153907
      Mar   -0.286818
      Apr   -0.306684
      May   -0.159371
      Jun   -0.230627
      Jul   -0.175845
```